# Google storage transfer service with Twilio

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, twilio, google-cloud-data-transfer

I am working with google cloud storage transfer service to transfer data from twilio recording url to google cloud bucket. While implementing above thing I came to know that to transfer a file from url you [must have a md5 hash of that object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/create-url-list).
Now twilio doesn't provide me with the md5 hash value.
I wanted to ask is it possible to do above thing and also along with that is there any other way to transfer the content of a url to directly on google cloud bucket.
Also I don't want to use my server for a very long amount of time it has to be quick like schedule so that i can track it or some kind of callback when it will get completed.

Comment: *"While implementing above thing I came to know that to transfer a file from url you must have a md5 hash of that object."* Please provide a citation for this requirement from the relevant GCS Transfer Service documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like whatever you do, you're going to need to download the recording files to your own server at some point during this process.

You could loop through the files, download them and generate the md5 hash for each of them, then discarding the file but creating the TSV of URLs and hashes as you go.

But, if you do that, you've done half the work in downloading the file, so you might as well continue to upload the file to Google Cloud Storage from that point, using [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) or the [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload).